# "High Accident Intersection"

Tags: word-choice, writing, word-order, meaning-in-context

I was challenged recently to solve this problem. An accident takes place on an intersection on a high road. However, if I was to write about this as taken place in a "high accident intersection" it would seem like a lot of accidents take place at that particular location. Is there a concise and accurate way of describing an accident at an intersection on a high altitude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to write a headline?

I would probably go with "high altitude intersection accident".

Comment: This was essentially the same answer I came to, but looking at it after a few weeks, I have no idea what the hell it means.

Answer (score 2):

The way you just did it would mean what you want: an intersection on which many accidents happen would be a *high-accident intersection*.

But frankly I find both phrasings a bit awkward; such a string of words without clear connections can be quite hard to parse for the reader, as your confusion would seem to prove. Brevity should step aside if clarity is getting trampled. I don't see how you could say this without prepositions or subordinate clauses.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the last nine words in your question, reworded slightly.

> an accident at an intersection at high altitude

Comment: It's not concise enough.

Comment: You could shave of a few letters with _an accident at a high-altitude intersection_ but it quickly gets less clear. _A high-altitude intersection accident_ while shorter, may trip up the reader a bit.  Can I ask why need for such concision? Do you need it to fit somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Here are my best shots:

> high intersection accident
>
> high altitude accident
>
> accident at a high altitude intersection

Comment: No.1 shot was best.

Comment: I don't think the meaning of 'high intersection accident' is clear at all. I certainly wouldn't know what to make of it.

Comment: I also think you need hyphens. *High-intersection* and *high-altitude* are compound adjectives here.

Comment: @Snub: That confusion is actually somewhat good, here. The original statement _wasn't_ confusing but led to the wrong meaning. This at least makes the reader think. But my opinion is that "high altitude accident" is the best option (hyphens or no hyphens) because I more or less agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

When you say *high road* do you mean *elevated*?

[image: elevated highway image]

If so, you could say *elevated-intersection accident*.

Answer (score 1):

In BE it's normally refereed to as an "accident black spot". This might not be appropriate in the USA

Answer (score 1):

An accident occurred at an intersection with highly elevated roads.

*or*

An intersection with elevated roads was the site of an accident.

I like using complete sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Would "accident-prone" intersection work?

Answer (score 0):

Using "high" to decorate "intersection" directly seems not accurate if you go with this:
"High intersection accident".

How about this:
High road intersection accident.

Comment: I think you need a hyphen in *high-road* here, because it is a compound adjective.

Answer (score -1):

How about 'high altitude road accident'?

Comment: I think you need a hyphen in *high-altitude*, possibly another one between *altitude* and road, because the three together form a compound adjective.